# Is there any software which can auto save buffered/cached videos?

Tags: video, software-rec, cache, firefox-extensions, browser-cache

I know there are many software which let you see the cache and then you have to save the video manually. But is there any software which will automatically save cached/buffered videos?

Also, if there is any firefox addon please let me know.

Comment: I haven't found anything that convenient. But the firefox extension DownloadHelper makes things a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy the video from the cache.

Under Linux open `/home/yourUsername/.mozilla/firefox/yourProfileid/Cache` under Windows it must be somewhere unter the path `%USERPROFILE%`.

Then you can find the most recent file by sorting by date. Or you clear the cache before you visit the video webpage to find the file easier.

Comment: Highly recommend clearing before watching... i just looked in my Cache, was 1GB and took ages to load. Also a huge mess to find things.